# Dini's theorem failing at a single point

Tags: uniform-convergence, monotone-functions, pointwise-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions $f_k: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ such that $f_{k + 1}(\beta) \leq f_k(\beta)$ for all $\beta$ (i.e monotone decreasing), and a continuous function $f: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$. If $f_k$ converges pointwise to $f$ for all $\beta \neq 0$ is it true that

1. $f_k$ converges pointwise to $f$ for all $\beta$?
2. $f_k$ converges uniformly to $f$?

If $f_k$ converges pointwise to $f$ at $\beta = 0$ then this is a simple application of Dini's theorem, but does it work when a single point is missing?

EDIT: A counterexample was pointed out in the comments for the general case. Would $f$ or $f_k$ being Lipschitz continuous or of bounded variation be sufficient however?

Comment: Something like $f_k(x)=(1-x)^k$?

Comment: Ah yes of course that makes sense thanks.

Comment: $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x)=\{1 \text{ if } x=0; 0 \text{ if } x \in (0,1] \}$. In other words, the pointwise limit $f(x)=\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x)$ is not continuous at $0$. Dini's theorem requires the assumption that the limit function is continuous on $[0,1]$ which should answer the question from your edit.